# WinForms code is not generated in c# visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have a problem with my C# Visual Studio 2010 Express. I'm writing a WinForms application, the code should've been generated automatically while I'm choosing some stuff in the properties tab. I mean this kind of thing:

```
this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(102,135);
this.button1.Name = "button1"; //etc.
```

Any suggestions how this code generation could be turned on? This just saves time rather then typing everything. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Generally that code is placed into a <formname>.designer.cs file and not in <formname>.cs.  If the designer is loading you can be sure that code is being generated somewhere.

Comment: Have you checked your form's Designer.cs file? For instance, `FormMain.Designer.cs`

Comment: You mean you create a Form and add a button but nothing is created in *.Designer.cs file?

Comment: Defiantly it is going to generate somewhere in designer file otherwise it will never be stored.

Comment: Thanks guys and sorry for disturbing you. I'm just learning and there is a mistake on the slides. It shows that all instantiations and settings are in FormName.cs file rather than Designer.cs. I also had to click the expand button to see the generated code.